# Laravel 5.4 token mismatch caused by a select field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am working on an old Laravel project (5.4) and i am not a stranger to Laravel's  TokenMismatchException. However, this case is weird and I tried several of the fixes I can do. A certain select field in one view is causing Laravel to throw this exception. This field is dynamically filled using Ajax based on the previous select input. The same combination of fields works perfectly when i am editing but doesn't work when I'm storing. Below is my code from the view:

```
<form action="{{ route('feedback.store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            {{ Form::booleanField('visible', '', '', [], 'Visible') }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <label for="employee_id">Employee</label><span class="required_field"></span>
            <select name="employee_id" id="employee_id" class="form-control">
                <option value="">----</option>
                @foreach($employees as $employee)
                    <option value="{{ $employee['id'] }}">{{ $employee['name'] }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <label for="period_id">{{ translate('Period') }}</label>
            <select id="period_id" name="periods_id" class="form-control"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
...
```

And here is the Ajax function to fill out the period field:

```
 $('#employee_id').on('change', function () {
            let id = $(this).val();

            if(id == null){
                return;
            }

            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                url: '/performance/employee-period/'+ id,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    let select = $('#period_id');
                    select.html(null);
                    select.append(new Option('---', ''));
                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        let option = new Option(value.period.start_date + ' - ' + value.period.end_date, value.period.id);
                        select.append(option);
                    })
                },
            });
        });
```

The route of the store is protected by the same middleware i use for all the other routes and they are not causing any issues. I have a meta containing the csrf token in the layout i am extending.
If I submit without choosing the period, the request passes directly.
It is probably something silly but i have wasted around 2 hrs trying to solve it without avail so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First notice: In ajax you use `get` method and you don't need `csrf`.

Second some times this problem cause by PHP. Change the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` and restart your `apache` or `nginx`

**Middle solution:**

You can remove csrf restrict from some routes from `App/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`.Bellow code ignore csrf token in all routes:

```
protected $except = [
   '/*'
];
```

But it's unsafe, just use it for test and debugging your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes I am aware of the ignoring csrf solution but as you said its very unsafe and allows exploits so i avoided it. I tried removing the csrf from the ajax and doing the php server changes as you suggested but the result is the same.

Comment: Removing  csrf is not very unsafe but it's unsafe.Sometimes in essential situation you can do it. But It's good to use it to find that the error is related to csrf or not.And It's better to use csrf.